# Multiple "sibling" controls, one-at-a-time visible, MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I've got what I think is a fairly simple problem in Silverlight, and I'd like to solve it using MVVM principles, largely as a way of enhancing my own understanding.

Let's say I have a simple LOB app that's designed to let me load up and edit a single Employee (just an example, for the sake of explanation). In my example, Employee is made up of a number of complex objects - an Employee has a ContactInfo, a Skillset, an EmploymentHistory, an AwardsEarned, etc. The idea is that I can have this app load up a single employee and get access to a number of different editor screens. Each component of an Employee has its own editor screen.

Visually, the app just ha a left-hand nav bar and a main view on the right side. The nav bar just lets me type in an employee number and load it into memory as the "active" employee. It has a simple list of links - clicking a link should load the appropriate editor screen on the right side.

There are a couple concepts that I don't think I understand well enough, and I'm having trouble proceeding. I know there's always more than one way to skin a cat, especially when it comes to WPF/Silverlight/XAML/MVVM, but I'm having trouble thinking through all the different concepts and their repurcussions.

**View-First or ViewModel First**

After much thinking about MVVM, what seems most natural to me is the concept of viewmodel composition that Josh Smith seems to [promote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090097) in his often-quoted article. It seems like the idea here is that you literally model your UI by composing viewmodels together, and then you let the viewmodels render themselves via typed DataTemplates. This feels like a very good separation of concerns to me, and it also makes viewmodel communication very direct and easy to understand.

Of course, Silverlight doesn't have the DataType property on DataTemplates, to many complaints: [one](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/29270/348768.aspx), [two](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559836/silverlight-4-datatemplate-support-datatype-property-required-for-mvvm-support#tabs). Regardless, what I see promoted much more often than viewmodel composition is a more view-first design, where the viewmodel for the view is typically instantiated in the view's XAML or via a DI container, meaning that you can't hand it any parameters. I'm having a really hard time understanding this: how is a ViewModel supposed to serve a Model to a View if I never get to tell it what data is in the model? Reaching through a view to get to its viewmodel doesn't seem to make sense either. I'm very hazy in this area but it seems the accepted answer "use a mediator/lightweight messaging framework." I'm just going through some tutorials now on the messaging system in MVVMLight and I'll be looking at similar stuff, if for nothing else than simply to understand the concepts, but if anyone can shed some light on this I'd very much appreciate it. Anything involving Unity/Prism or MEF is valid, but I haven't gotten that far in my quest for knowledge yet :-)

**Instantiating Views and Selecting Them**

Theoretically (I say that because SL doesn't support DataTemplate DataType), the viewmodel composition approach could make this very simple. I could have the right side of the screen be a content control whose Content property is bound to a property called ActiveEditor. A parameterized command for the hyperlinks would set ActiveEditor to a given viewmodel.

With a more view-first approach, how would I proceed with this? The first thing that comes to mind is instantiating all of the controls in the XAML of the main view.

Is manipulating the Content property of a ContentControl a good way to go for this kind of situation, or am I better off doing something like setting visibility on each individual control?

Answer (score 1):

The ViewModel (VM) is written so that it is 'wired up' to the Model but has no knowledge at all of the View - in fact, this is what makes it very good to unit test ([see NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)) as it has no idea, and less does it care, whether it is being used by a UI or a Test Framework.

The VM exposes public CLR properties which implement the ICommand interface, the View, having instantiated a VM using (generally speaking anyway) its default constructor, then binds its Buttons/Hyperlinks etc to these Command properties like. So, for example, you may have a VM that exposes a CloseCommand to exit the app, the View may contain a MenuItem that binds to that command, such as:

```
<MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" />
```

Now, the VM would also expose a public ObservableCollection of objects that you want to display in your UI. Whether you populate this ObservableCollection as part of the VM constructor, or whether you do it via a UI interaction (say another Command assigned to a Button click) is up to you but the end result is that you bind a View control to this exposed ObservableCollection in XAML like:

```
<y:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Breakdown}"/>
```

or equivelant for whatever control you are using to display the data (not sure off the top of my head what elements a DataGrid has in Silverlight as opposed to WPF).

Meanwhile...: The Mediator pattern is used for VM's to interact with each other, not for the View to interact with the VM. For example, you might have a custom TreeView that has its own VM on the same View as the main chart screen. In this case you could use a Mediator for the TreeView's VM to communicate with the Charts VM.

As for the last bit of your question, I think set up a basic framework using Josh Smith way in the article you mentioned and use that method to add additional ViewModels to the right hand side of your silverlight app.

Hope that helps a bit at least.